# displaying page header only for the table structure

Tags: crystal-reports

The page header should be displayed only for the table structure and if the detail does not contain any data then also it should not display page header in the next page,what should i do for this?
[image]

I have tried with this
[image]

[image]

I want the page header for all the table structure like total,total2 and total value?

[image]

I don't want page header to be displayed if the fields like amount1,sales,contract and amount field goes to next page?

inside shared variables formula i have written the following code below.

```
Shared stringVar total_value;
Shared NumberVar page_number;
if OnlastRecord then page_number := PageNumber;
if OnlastRecord then total_value := {@Total Value};
```

inside suppress section of page header i have written the following code

```
Shared stringvar total_value;
Shared NumberVar page_number;
page_number := page_number;
total_value := total_value;
if(pagenumber > 1 and StrCmp (total_value,"")=1) THEN true
else false
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please paste your actual code, rather than snapshots of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for above question is that I have to place my shared variable in place of amount1 field,it will work that time